# Java BlockingQueue cause threads wait unnecessarily.

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I'm using BlockingQueue(LinkedBlockingQueue) to synchronise data among several threads. Please see the picture below.

The main thread is a producer which produces objects and then put them into the queue of each Consumer (thread 2-10). Need to emphasis that each consumer has its own queue and each object produced will goto all consumer's queues.

Producer runs much faster than the consumers so we could assume the queue shouldn't be empty during Consumers' run. Producer will be blocked when any consumer's queue reaches its capacity (`put()` is used by Producer). Consumer takes objects from the queue using `take()`.

With this setting, I would assume the consumer will rarely (if possible at all) be awaiting while queue is empty. However, from the picture I attached below, I can see that from time to time, all Consumers have to wait on the queue to be filled with objects; during the wait time I can see the producer is running.

It is not what my understanding of BlockingQueue, I had assumed that as long as the producer produce something and put in the queue, the consumer should start work. Why there such big waiting time on the consumer thread is beyond my understanding.

Can someone explain it a bit more? Is there any easy way to profile this kinds of application?

[image: thread waiting]

Comment: Have you tried using an ExecutorService which wraps up a Queue and a Thread Pool?  What are the advantages of your system over using an existing library?

Comment: It is a bit different from ExecutorService's framework. Each object produced need to be processed by all the consumer thread. In ExecutorService, only one worker will work on the job submitted. I'm willing to see if there is anyway to adjust ExecutorService to work with this design though, but I havn't found the solution yet.

Comment: Is this because each thread does different work based on that object?  Have you looked at the Disruptor library as this is designed to be a higher performance version of what you are trying to do. i.e. split the work for each event across multiple threads.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?  Please upvote and/or accept if so.

Answer (score 1):

> It is not what my understanding of BlockingQueue, I had assumed that as long as the producer produce something and put in the queue, the consumer should start work. Why there such big waiting time on the consumer thread is beyond my understanding.

This most likely is *not* a problem with the `BlockingQueue`.

1. You may be incorrect and the producer is falling behind the consumers.  Maybe the producer is bursting and once and a while is reading from a loaded disk and falls behind.
2. Maybe the consumers are blocking on some *other* object and not the `BlockingQueue`.  What are the consumers doing with the data?  Are they writing it to disk or sending it over the network?  Any other operations that they do that can block?
3. Another possibility is that only a couple of threads are keeping up with the producer and the so a number of the threads are waiting in a LIFO thread order.  In other words, if a thread had just finished, maybe it takes the latest element added by the producer.  So a couple of threads stay busy and other threads stay in blocked more.  I'm not sure if that's how your queue is implemented.

> Is there any easy way to profile this kinds of application?

One thing to do is to look at your stack traces to see *where* each of the threads is blocked.  This will give you a better idea if your threads are actually waiting on the blocking queue.  You can use jconsole to look at the threads live or send a `QUIT` signal every so often.